# Serialization POCO proxy with WCF

Tags: wcf, serialization, entity-framework-4.1, poco

When I run my service I got exception:

*The server encountered an error processing the request. The exception message is 'Cannot serialize parameter of type System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.Cosik_14C2...' (for operation 'GetCosik', contract 'ICosikService') because it is not the exact type 'Project.Domain.Entities.Cosik' in the method signature and is not in the known types collection. In order to serialize the parameter, add the type to the known types collection for the operation using ServiceKnownTypeAttribute.'. See server logs for more details.*

I'm new to WCF services and Entity Framework and I'd appreciate any help/suggestions.

I'm using Entity Framework 4.1. Using code-first I created database with two tables:

```
[DataContract(IsReference=true)]
public class Cosik
{
    [DataMember]
    public int cosikID { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string title { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public int DifficultyID { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public virtual Difficulty Difficulty { get; set; }
}

[DataContract(IsReference=true)]
public class Difficulty
{
    [DataMember]
    public int DifficultyID { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    [Required]
    public string NameToDisplay { get; set; }
}
```

Next I created the WCF service application and made it RESTful. Below is code for interface:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface ICosikService
{
    [OperationContract]
    [ApplyDataContractResolver]
    [WebGet(UriTemplate = "/cosik")]
    Cosik GetCosik();
}
```

and implementation of that contract

```
public class RecipeService : IRecipeService
{
//repository of Cosik entities - stores collection of all
//Cosik entities that can be queried from DB
private ICosikRepository cosikRepo;
...

public Cosik GetCosik()
    {
        Cosik c = cosikRepo.GetById(1);
        return c;
    }
```

I implemented ApplyDataContractResolverAttribute class given on: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee705457.aspx and added [ApplyDataContractResolver] annotation to GetCosik method. However, it didn't help.

Any suggestion what I've missed?

Comment: It looks like the *Cosik* in your service operation GetCosik() and which you have marked as a data contract is not the same *Cosik* as is defined in your entity model and which your service is for some reason trying to return.

Comment: Do you still get the same error if you disable lazy loading in your [ObjectContext](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.objectcontext.aspx) by using   `context.ContextOptions.LazyLoadingEnabled = false`?

Comment: Can you add [KnownType(Cosik)] above your RecipeService class.

Comment: When I switch of proxy creation I don't get an error, but Difficulty field in retrieved Cosik is null. I could query the database again to get the right Difficulty object and set the Difficulty field by myself. But in this way I loose the whole lot of functionality provided by EF. Is there a way not to loose it?

I've already tried [KnownType(Cosik)] and I still got the same error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of developing custom resolver turn off proxy creation. Proxies are not for scenarios like WCF because lazy loading must be turned off anyway during serialization and dynamic change tracking is never used:

```
context.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
```

Comment: By turning off proxy creation all my virtual objects(fields) become null and I loose the functionality provided by EF. I'm wondering if that is really the case that I have to query the database to set virtual fields with the appropriate data on my own.
 
I went through a lot of pages explaining how to use wcf with simple examples for simple data but simple data is rather scarse in the real world. Can anyone point me to some resources/tutorial that explain how to use rest wcf with EF on more complex data? 
Now I use wcf(without rest) and it works but I'd like to learn how to use it in rest-way

Comment: Your virtual fields are null because you didn't use eager loading. Using lazy loading in situations where you know that you will need that data is not correct because EF must create separate database roundtrip for "every property".

Comment: @anetafr For better REST support, check out the project item type 'WCF Data Service', which can be used with code-first, though it does have it's own hurdles (http://blogs.msdn.com/b/writingdata_services/archive/2011/06/15/entity-framework-4-1-code-first-and-wcf-data-services.aspx). Personally I'd opt for the cleaner option of translating between entities and DTO's in my service layer. Anyways, a couple other options for you to think about..

Comment: Dynamic change tracking is never used in WCF? Why do you think that?

Comment: @jannagy02: Because dynamic change tracking is used to push change notification to the context when property on the entity is modified. That does not work well with WCF. When the change is done on the client you cannot push individual notifications and when you receive call to service all changes are already applied to received entity and you will most probably not modify individual properties on another attached instance of the entity just to replay changes done on the client.